# How to make use of End="" parameter within function

Tags: python, function, methods, parameters, frontend

### I have been tasked to create a parallelogram using the required function below

```
def repeatChar(numRepeats, outputChar):
    '''
    output the outputChar numRepeats times on the same line
    '''
    for colNo in range(numRepeats):
        print(outputChar, end='')  # print outputChar and stay on the same line (don't go to next line)
```

I have created a working solution but it fails to meet the requirements of the function above due to my lack of understanding how to properly make use of the *End* parameter So ultimately my question is how would i integrate it into my code below . I have tried substituting the declarations of escape sequence newline "\n" at the end each for loop in my main function for a 'print(outputChar, end="\n")' within my repeatChar function but the output of the parallelogram comes out a bit funky in comparison

##### Working Solution but does not make proper use of the *End* parameter

```
def repeatChar(numRepeats, outputChar):
        output = ""
        for colNo in range(numRepeats):
            output += outputChar
        return output
   
    
    def main():
        print("This program will output a prallelogram.")
        side = int(input("How long do you want wach side to be? "))
        char = input("Please enter the character you want it to be made of: ")
        output = ""
        
        # loop to output the top triangle
        for topTriangle in range(1, side + 1):
            output += repeatChar(topTriangle, char) + "\n"
    
        # loop to output the bottom triangle
        for btmTriangle in range(1, side + 1):
            output += repeatChar(btmTriangle, " ") + repeatChar((side - btmTriangle), char) + "\n"
        print(output)
    
    
    main()
```

[view sample output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZhiF.png)

Comment: Your function `repeatChar` is useless. Python has this built-in: `'@' * 3` => `'@@@'`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a function with signature:

```py
def print_line(characters: List[str]):
    """print_line will print the list of characters to console"""
```

There are trivial solutions here using the standard library, but to follow your exercise using `print`'s `end` parameter, you could implement this as:

```py
def print_line(characters: List[str]):
    for ch in characters:
        print(ch, end='')
    print()  # output the trailing newline
```

Consider how you could rework this into your own code, something like:

```py
def repeat_character(n: int, ch: str):
    for _ in range(n):
        print(ch, end='')
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def repeatChar(numRepeats, outputChar, endchar='\n'):
    '''
    output the outputChar numRepeats times on the same line
    '''
    print(outputChar*numRepeats, end=endchar)
```

If you want it to work properly don't put print in a loop char by char.